# SELECT query without last N rows

Tags: mysql

How to select all rows of a mysql table without last N(any integer value) rows.

I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM 
           chat 
         WHERE chat_id NOT IN(
                    SELECT chat_id FROM chat ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 5
                );
```

But it gives following error

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I am getting current MySQL version as following

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
+---------------+------------------+
| Variable_name | Value            |
+---------------+------------------+
| version       | 5.1.33-community |
+---------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to filter out rows matching a criteria.

```
SELECT c1.*
FROM chat AS c1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT chat_id
           FROM chat
           ORDER BY date_time DESC
           LIMIT 5) AS c2 ON c1.chat_id = c2.chat_id
WHERE c2.chat_id IS NULL
```